# OroCrm - making symfony2 profiler update the footer data correctly without throwing 404 page in a popup

Tags: javascript, symfony, orocrm

I'm new to OroCrm, and I've installed it and configured it to work on DEV environment using app_dev.php entry point.

First thing I noticed was that the symfony2 profiler bar appeared at the bottom. This is great, but when I switch pages, by browsing through the interface, the pages are loading correctly but the profiler remains unchanged (not updated for the last served request), and I also get a 404 page in a popup.

I've managed to fix this by modifying **web/bundles/oronavigation/js/navigation.js** (line 544) from:

```
                var url = entryPoint + '/_wdt/' + debugBarToken;
```

to:

```
                if ('/' ===  entryPoint.charAt(entryPoint.length - 1)) {
                    var url = entryPoint + '_wdt/' + debugBarToken;
                }
                else {
                    var url = entryPoint + '/_wdt/' + debugBarToken;
                }
```

These seems to work for me. The profiler debug is refreshed after every page request.
I would like to see more opinions on this, and maybe different solutions on how you achieved this.

**UPDATE**: OroCrm 1.1.0 doesn't give any error, but the debugbar status is locked to the DashboardController even if you switch sections and navigate on other pages. The above code update makes the debugbar display current request status (is not being locked anymore to DashboardController).

Answer (score 0):

Now it's outdated, consider to switch/upgrade to latest version